# How to add data in a QTable using method setItem?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyside

I am currently trying to add some data from a nested dictionary into a QTableWidget by using the method setItem()

When I run my code I doesn't return an error and also my data are not loaded ( my table is generating the right amount of column regarding the number of elements in my dictionary thought ). I also tried to pass a string as a last parameter of the method setItem() but again nothing appears in my table.

The structure of my dictionary is similar to this one :

```
dict_of_instruments= {'GHI': {'manufacturer': 'Samsong', 'instrument': 'pyranometer', 'class': 'A'},
          'DNI': {'manufacturer': 'Urus', 'instrument': 'manometer', 'class': 'B'}}
```

There is my code :

```
  def populate_table_instruments_measurements(self, source="custom"):
    # calulation of the total number of instruments in the dictionnary
    row = len(dict_of_instruments['GHI']) + len(dict_of_instruments['DNI']) + len(dict_of_instruments['DIF']) + len(
        dict_of_instruments['ALB']) + len(dict_of_instruments['GTI']) + len(dict_of_instruments['RHI'])
    column = 4

    # set the numbers of row regarding the number of value in the dictionnary
    self.table_instruments_measurements.setRowCount(row)
    self.table_instruments_measurements.setColumnCount(column)
    print(dict_of_instruments['DNI'])

    row_count = 0
    for id, info in enumerate(dict_of_instruments):
        print("___________")
        row_count=row_count+1
        for col, key in enumerate(info):
            print(key)
            self.table_instruments_measurements.setItem(row_count,0,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(info)))
```

Comment: You said "my table is generating the right amount of column regarding the number of elements in my dictionary" but in your code you're setting the *row* count, not the column. If that's the case, where are you setting the column count? Otherwise, you didn't set the column count, and that's the reason for which you can't set any item, the default model has *both* row and column count equal to 0, and you need to set both counts > 0 in order to successfully set any item.

Comment: Hi mate thank you for your comment, I managed to be able to access my item but now I am wondering how to set the right value(e.g: Samsong from the manufacturer key). I tried to turn my code around and i can only return the 1st key of my dictionary I am sorry if I misunderstood what you meant... New to this technology here.. I updated my code thought

Comment: This has nothing to do with PyQt, but with basic python: if you want to iterate through a nested dictionary, you need to access *both* keys and values. The `info` you get in the first for loop is the *key* of the main dictionary, so if you want to create items for each sub-dict, you should then use `for col, (key, value) in enumerate(dict_of_instruments[info]):`. Remember that dictionaries respect the insertion order only since Python 3.6, so, unless you're **absolutely sure** that you're not using a previous version, you should use nested lists (or tuples) instead of dictionaries.